# SQL Server - import bacpac file of Azure SQL database to SQL Server 2014 on Virtual Machine

Tags: sql-server, azure

We are moving our Azure SQL Database to SQL Server 2014 on an Azure Virtual Machine.  I created a bacpac file of the Azure SQL Database.

Upon trying to import the bacpac into the SQL Server on the VM, I'm met with the following error:

> Could not import package. Warning SQL0: A project which specifies
>   Microsoft Azure SQL Database v12 as the target platform may experience
>   compatibility issues with SQL Server 2014. Warning SQL72012: The
>   object [NegativeMedia_Prod_Data] exists in the target, but it will not
>   be dropped even though you selected the 'Generate drop statements for
>   objects that are in the target database but that are not in the
>   source' check box. Warning SQL72012: The object
>   [NegativeMedia_Prod_Log] exists in the target, but it will not be
>   dropped even though you selected the 'Generate drop statements for
>   objects that are in the target database but that are not in the
>   source' check box. Error SQL72014: .Net SqlClient Data Provider: Msg
>   7738, Level 16, State 2, Line 1 Cannot enable compression for object
>   'Captures'. Only SQL Server Enterprise Edition supports compression.

The way I see it, I have two options:

1. Upgrade SQL Server on the VM - a little scary to me based on the fact that we have existing data there.  Is the upgrade process somewhat straightforward?  Based on this:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/install-windows/upgrade-sql-server it sure looks like anything BUT straightforward.
2. Figure out a workaround to get this database imported into SQL Server 2014.  As far as the compression part goes, I can turn that off in the Azure SQL database and recreate the bacpac file.  The rest of the error message then is what I would need to "work around" but I don't fully understand its meaning.

Whichever of the two above options can be achieved in the least amount of time is what I need, in order to keep the boss happy.  Please let me know if anyone has any suggestions on either.

Answer (score 2):

Upgrade from SQL Server 2014 to SQL Server 2016 was a quick and painless process.  It's certainly come a long way.  I have upgraded and have now successfully imported the bacpac file.